# C++: Scoping issues when using a debug variable for a program

Tags: c++, debugging, scope, global-variables

I am writing a program where I would like to easily switch on/off my debug code. This program is not production level - it is for a programming competition.

I have only a single file, `main.cpp`, so I thought a debug variable might be acceptable. I considered the use of a global variable, as follows:

```
bool DEBUG = true;

int main()
{

    if (DEBUG)
    {
         // print debug statements and other debug code
    }
    // rest of program...
```

However, I get a warning that my `DEBUG` variable is never used and `if (DEBUG)` is always evaluating to false. Alternatively, I can bring my `DEBUG` variable inside the `main()` method:

```
int main()
{
    bool DEBUG = true;
    if (DEBUG)
    {
         // print debug statements and other debug code
    }
    // rest of program...
```

But then I get a compiler warning 'Condition is always true`. Any suggestions on how to easily switch on/off my`DEBUG` code? An explanation for the compiler issues would be great.

Comment: Typically these flags are set using some external prodding. e.g. reg key setting. You should explore this as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Common way is to use the pre-processor

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
// debug code
#endif

// or

#ifdef DEBUG
// debug code
#endif
```

Although one project I worked on NDEBUG was undef'd and replaced with another one so check that it exists.

I wouldn't also be surprised that your warning is because there is also a #define DEBUG already present. so your variable DEBUG is never used.

Usually DEBUG and NDEBUG are defined by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] I would like to easily switch on/off my debug code [...] Any suggestions on how to easily switch on/off myDEBUG` code?

Consider this:

```
bool debug = false; // set default value on compilation
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using std::literals::string_literals;

    std::vector<std::string> args{ argv, argv + argc };
    if(std::end(args) != std::find(std::begin(args), std::end(args), "-d"s))
        debug = true; // reset debug flag based on runtime parameter
    // use debug from this point onwards
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./your-app # run with compiled flag
$ ./your-app -d # run with debug information
```

Notes:

- The `"-d"s` construct requires `using std::literals::string_literals;`.
- You could set the default debug flag based on a compilation macro (DEBUG, _DEBUG and NDEBUG are the most common on Windows)
- Consider using `boost::program-options` if you want more complex parameters handling.